# Two scroll view in android?

Tags: android

```
parentscrollview
      linearlayout1(parentscrollview.at(0))
             tv_title (linearlayout1.at(0))
             relativelayout(linearlayout1.at(1))
                    linearlayout2(relativelayout.at(0))
                            tv_text(linearlayout2.at(0))
                            childScrollview(linearlayout2.at(1))
```

Above is the view which I have created programatically,now I want to stop scroll parentscroll view when i scroll child scroll view and vice versa...I know I can use this..

```
    parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "PARENT TOUCH");

        findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});

childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

need help for my view...

Comment: But why do you want that? It's not a good idea.

Comment: yes...but I am creating view dynamically,so it required to be like this..is there any way..?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: i just want to use the above touch listeners.but if i touch on child scrollview  my parent scroll view is not getting stop scrolling.

Comment: That's the only reason why I wrote "It's not a good idea".

Comment: what should i do now any idea?

Comment: Come talk here: [Android Discussions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71661/android-discussions).